# Why is docker-compose output sent to StandardError in ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm using `ProcessStartInfo` to run a `docker-compose` command. The command runs successfully with no errors, but the `StandardError` stream has actual data/text. Any idea why and how I pipe that to `StandardOutput` instead?

Command:

```
ProcessStartInfo commandInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
    "docker-compose",
    "-p mynodename -f my-compose-file.yml up -d"
);

//Capture the output
commandInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
commandInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

Process process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = commandInfo
};

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

if (process.ExitCode == 0)
{
    //Why is there something here?
    string error = process.StandardError?.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Here's the output:

> "Creating redis_node...
>   \u001b[1A\u001b[2K
>   Creating redis_node...
>   \u001b[32mdone\u001b[0m\r\u001b[1B

Comment: I think just because it says it's a StandardError stream, doesn't necessarily mean it's an error. Even in the example Microsoft gives for StandardOutput, they use StandardError to send a successful status. Perhaps, StandardOutput is a more detailed event output and StandardError is more of a general status for docker-compose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Stderr is quite often used for reporting progress, for example. Tools like FFmpeg and git do that as well.